# Updating sort column in ASP.NET with Request.QueryString Array

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm passing a list of guids in a GET request from a JQuery Ajax call.

on my ASP.NET controller side I want to iterate through the list and update the Display_Sort column to match my newly sorted list.

My ID is a Guid and I'm getting a type error in the following code, because it's a string that I'm passing to the Db. However, I can't seem to convert the item(string) into a Guid.

I've tried Guid(item) and it would allow the constructor. Not sure what I'm missing.

Here is the code:

```
        //REORDER HOME ASSETS
    public ActionResult ReOrderHome()
    {
        using (var db = new IFEntities())
        {
            var myString = Request.QueryString;
            var i = 1;

            foreach (var item in myString)
            {
               var myObj = db.HomeContents.Find(item);
                myObj.display_order = i;
                db.SaveChanges();
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `item` to `GUID` and then compare like this.

`var myObj = db.HomeContents.Find(new Guid(item));`

Or, you can use `select` instead of `find`. Syntax for select --

```
foreach (var item in myString)
{
    var myObj = db.HomeContents.Select(p => p.<GUID_COLUMN_NAME> == item);
    myObj.display_order = i;
    db.SaveChanges();
    i++;
}
```

Replace `GUID_COLUMN_NAME` with actual column name.